# Icemaker nosiy when it cycles on

Tags: refrigerator, ice-maker

My GE fridge’s ice maker makes an annoying sound when the ice maker cycles on.

- [This video shows the sound starting after ice is dispensed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mls57.jpg)
- [This video focuses on the sound. With the freezer door open is it much louder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7dHn.jpg).

The sound usually lasts about 5 minutes, and then goes silent. It seems to start when the icemaker starts a new batch of ice. If the bin is full and the icemaker is not making ice, the sound will not start. But usually after dispensing ice, there will be room in the bin and the noise will start.

It’s been like this for years, and I would love to get it fixed.

The icemaker performance seems fine - it makes plenty of ice, no trouble dispensing.

Fridge is GE 82NK Household Refrigerator, Model DSE25JSHECSS.

Comment: In the video I hear loud ice in the glass, and then a sort of thud.  Is the noise the thud?

Comment: Thanks for the interest! No, the thud is just the door to the chute closing all the way, I think. It's the background noise, sort of a rocking sound at about 240 cycles per minute.

Comment: how did you manage to grab ice at the precise moment the tray is filling? I would think that would only happen once in a blue moon. I'm not sure i can hear what you're talking about in the video, all i hear is the freeze fan noise while the flapper is open....

Comment: I'll get a new video trying to draw more attention to the sound. Typically it goes something like this: bin is full, so no ice is being made. Get some ice, the bin sensor notices room in the bin, starts making ice and the noise starts. Or, if the bin is low, every time you hear finished ice cubes drop in the bin, the noise starts right after.

Comment: @dandavis I've put a 2nd video up where the sound is much more noticeable.

Comment: it's rotating rake that scoops out the frozen cubes, they take a min or two to run. you might be able to lubricate any axis, gears, or bearings attached to it to quiet it down. I don't know what would work for that though, low-temp food-safe lubrication? Maybe something common like a vegetable oil?

Comment: That's super helpful to know! I'm finding aerosol cans of food-grade silicone lubricant that say they're good down to -40F. Thanks!